# Troubles with Sheets(Array(...)) and For Each Looped Formatting between sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have been wracking my brain trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with my coding.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to apply formatting to each sheet in my workbook - regardless of name.  My first attempt, I used a `For Each` loop for each sheet, and then use a `For Each` loop to change the format of a column based on the headers of a range of cells that both exist in the same spots on each sheet.  What I have now will *work* but I have to loop the loop TWICE to get things to *"Stick".*

My code is Below:

```
Sub A4()
'This sets widths for all machine types and sets up error code column formatting
Dim Sht As Worksheet

For Each Sht In Worksheets
Sht.Activate

    With Sht.UsedRange
Set SrchRng = Range("A3:G4")
        For Each cel In SrchRng
            If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Item", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, cel.Value, "Event", vbTextCompare) Then
            cel.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 24
            GoTo Next1
            End If
        Next cel
Next1:
        For Each cel In SrchRng
            If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Time", vbTextCompare) Then
              If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Date", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, cel.Value, "(Time", vbTextCompare) Then
              cel.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 18.57
              Else: cel.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 11
              End If
            GoTo Next2
            End If
        Next cel

Next2:
        For Each cel In SrchRng
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Date", vbTextCompare) Then
                    If (InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, -1).Value, "Event", vbTextCompare) And InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, "Time", vbTextCompare)) _
                Or (InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, -1).Value, "Running", vbTextCompare) And InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, "Time", vbTextCompare)) Then
                cel.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 11
                Else: cel.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 19.4
                End If
            GoTo Next3
            End If
        Next cel

Next3:
    Set SrchRng = Range("E:E")
        With SrchRng
            If InStr(1, Range("E3").Value, "Error", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, Range("E3").Value, "Process Step", vbTextCompare) Then
            Range("E3").Value = "Error"
            .Replace "0x", "", xlPart
            .NumberFormat = "0000"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            GoTo Next4
            End If
        End With

    Set SrchRng = Range("D:D")
        With SrchRng
            If InStr(1, Range("D4").Value, "Error", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, Range("D4").Value, "Process Step", vbTextCompare) Then
            Range("D4").Value = "Error"
            .Replace "0x", "", xlPart
            .NumberFormat = "0000"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            End If
        End With


Next4:
Next Sht
End With
'Now I look in each sheet to see if any of the ColumnWidths are still at the standard 8.43 (20 Pixels).
'It will check the first sheet "Unit01" which is set correctly, and goes straight to the next sheet.
'Since the next sheet is not changed, then it repeats the A4 Subroutine, and this second time it sticks.
For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Sht.Activate
If Range("B:B").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth < 9 Then
A4
End If
Next Sht
Sheets("Unit01_0F_PROC0").Activate
End Sub
```

It has to loop through the code twice in order for it to perform the task for both sheets.

Then, I learned by recording the Macro that I can use

```
Sheets(Array("Unit01", "Totals")).Select '(activate won't work here)
```

to select both of the sheets. I don't want to call out the specific range for the columns that are being changed, because this code is used to read multiple files with different column data, albeit with a few constants.  Their Column location changes, so that's why I use `For Each` and `InStr()` to find the column that corresponds.  SO,  Trying that out I have this:

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim SchRng As Range

'
Sheets(Array(Sheets.Count, 1, Sheets.Count, 2)).Select
With Selection
    Set SchRng = Range("A3:G4")
    For Each cel In SchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Date", vbTextCompare) Then
    cel.ColumnWidth = 20.57

    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 14.43
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 7.71
    Columns("E:F").Select
    Range("F1").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 6.57
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Lalaoo"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Dood"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Dard"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Fard"
    Range("F2").Select
    End If
    Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

But ***this didn't work either...***  I'm at a loss here, scratching my head.

Comment: You have `With` blocks in your code, but you never make use of the functionality.  (Actually, you do use it in your `With SrchRng` blocks, but I think they are the only ones.) A `With` block allows you to "shortcut" your typing by simply using `.` instead of `someObject.`  It doesn't magically make something happen to the `With` object.  So **try** using `Set SchRng = .Range("A3:G4")`, etc, in your last block of code.

Comment: Please, reformat the code.

Comment: @ YowE3K, I've tried `Set SchRng = .Range("A3:G4")` so that it's automatically implied, but that didn't solve the issue.  I tried it in both sets of code to check.  When using the `Sheets(Array())` method, I see the changes take place on the first sheet, but when I check the 2nd, it doesn't change.

Comment: @ JohnyL, I looked through the post, and you're right -- I had some things that I didn't call out.  Is there anything glaring that I missed, or is it a general request to restructure the code I did provide (if it wasn't the code I forgot to call out)?

Comment: THIS IS SO STRANGE!  The only thing I have changed now, is adding `.` to the `Range("A3:G4")`, and remove it, and now it's updating both sheets with the original loop.  Does anyone have any idea what would've been the issue?